# Using setState with props from parent element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use setState on a click to update my element with a property passed from a parent element, but the state of my element won't update.

I've tried adding and removing "this" to a few spots and also having everything in the constructor function, but for whatever reason the state still doesn't change.

```
    changeToBlack = (e)=>{
        this.setState({
            buttonClicked:'black'})
        }

  render(){
      return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.changeToRed}>change To Red</button>
      <button onClick={this.changeToBlack}>change To Black</button>
      <div className="grid">
      <Square button={this.state.buttonClicked} color={this.state.colorToChangeMaze} className= 'cell'/>
      <Square button={this.state.buttonClicked} color={this.state.colorToChangeMaze}className= 'cell'/>
      <Square button={this.state.buttonClicked} color={this.state.colorToChangeMaze}className= 'cell'/>
      <Square button={this.state.buttonClicked} color={this.state.colorToChangeMaze}className= 'cell'/>
      <Square button={this.state.buttonClicked} color={this.state.colorToChangeMaze}className= 'cell'/>
      <Square button={this.state.buttonClicked} color={this.state.colorToChangeMaze}className= 'cell'/>
      <Square button={this.state.buttonClicked} color={this.state.colorToChangeMaze}className= 'cell'/>
      <Square button={this.state.buttonClicked} color={this.state.colorToChangeMaze}className= 'cell'/>
      <Square button={this.state.buttonClicked} color={this.state.colorToChangeMaze}className= 'cell'/> 
      </div>
      </div>
  );}
}

class Square extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          color: 'orange',
          colorToChange:null,
          changeColor: false
        };
      }
    switchColor =(e)=>{
        this.setState({
            changeColor:true,
            colorToChange:this.props.button})
}
    render(){
        return(
            <input onMouseOver = {this.switchColor} style={{'height':'74px','width':'74px','backgroundColor':this.state.changeColor?this.state.color:this.state.colorToChange,'margin':'0'}}>
            </input>
        )
    }
```

I'm really unsure why the colorToChange stays at null and the changeColor stays at false. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to switch these variables round as at the moment it will set the background color to `null` then once you hover over the input it will always set it to `this.state.color` which is always orange.

You should change:

```
this.state.changeColor?this.state.color:this.state.colorToChange
```

To:

```
this.state.changeColor ? this.state.colorToChange : this.state.color
```